# coding style question: using event to store data without yielding a state

Tags: flutter, layout, bloc

I haven't found a neat way to get my available screen size on iOS devices, so far. Now I have an idea, which is quite unconventional, and would be interested, if there is any issue with it on the horizon or if someone has a better idea.

The idea is to determine the available screen size with the position and size of SafeArea on the splash screen and then to store this with an event to a bloc, after rendering, but without triggering any state change. The bloc would then provide the information to other widgets in the tree.

```dart
class _SplashPageState extends State<SplashPage> {
  final safeAreaKey = GlobalKey();
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(_afterLayout);
  }
  _afterLayout(_) {
    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context)
        .add(AuthenticationScreenSizeDetermined(
          getPosition(safeAreaKey, context, null), 
          getSize(safeAreaKey, context)));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        key: safeAreaKey,
        child: Text('Init'),
          ),
    ));
  }
}
```

This is because I have not found the variables so far, which provide info on the size of system bars of iOS (for Android, they are available).

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this too:

inside build()

```
// full screen width and height
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

// height without SafeArea
var padding = MediaQuery.of(context).padding;
double height1 = height - padding.top - padding.bottom;

// height without status bar
double height2 = height - padding.top;

// height without status and toolbar
double height3 = height - padding.top - kToolbarHeight;
```

**EDIT**

```
double bottomPadding = MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.bottom;
```

Comment: yes, kToolbarHeight is Android only, unfortunately

Comment: try this `MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top;`

Comment: If I have a CupertinoPageScaffold on top, `viewPadding.top` still provides 0.0 as upper position. And, as I said, `kToolBar` also does not provide a correct value for this. Typically, this is not an issue until you work with `Positioned()`